# vim - how do I yank to register inside a function?

Tags: vim, vim-registers

I am perplexed how to use the registers from inside a function.  For example, if I want to yank the current word to register "k", from inside vim, I would use the command/keystrokes

```
"kyw
```

But this does not work from inside a function: `"` starts a comment:

```
function MyFunction()
  "kyw
  "^^^ does not work because it is a comment...
  let @k="I can set register k directly to text..."
  " but that's not the same
  yank k "I can yank an entire line, but still not the same
endfunction
```

Is there a way to do this without changing the comment option (would that even work?)  Thanks; I have been hitting my head against this for an entire day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either

- `:normal! "kyw` (recurring question),
- or `:let @k = expand('<cword>')` if you're at the start of the word. Note that in that case, it's better to avoid storing the value of the current word in a register: it's better to use variables and to leave registers alone (or at least unchanged) when we can.

Comment: Thank you!  I have already started looking into whether I can accomplish the same goals with variables; I will perhaps see if it's possible to do it that way and prefer to do it.

Comment: As it turns out, using variables was easy.  Thanks for answering this tho - I was sure there was a way to do it, but couldn't find anything!